# Assign value to value of a variable in SQL

Tags: sql, hana, sql-scripts, hana-sql-script

I have a variable called `LV_MAIN` which is having value as `LV_TEMP` and now I want to assign value to `LV_TEMP` and write select for `LV_TEMP`. How can I achieve this?

To explain in detail:

```
LV_MAIN := LV_TEMP
```

and now I want to assign:

```
LV_TEMP := '7'
```

and want to execute:

```
SELECT :LV_TEMP FROM DUMMY;
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `set`. Sql Server doesn't use the dummy table.

Comment: i know sql server do not use dummy table... i am writing it in HANA ... ignore about database ..... kindly let me know if there is any solution for my query ??

Answer (score 1):

To execute SQL Script, a "logic container" is required.

This "logic container" can be a trigger, a stored procedure, a table function, or an anonymous block.

For simple once-off queries or prototyping, the anonymous block is the option most readily usable:

```
DO BEGIN -- this indicates the start of the anon. block
DECLARE lv_temp NVARCHAR(2) := '7';

SELECT 
     :lv_temp 
FROM 
    DUMMY;

END; -- this indicates the end of the anon. block
```